# How to extract string between two characters with sed

Tags: sed

I need some help with `sed`. I have tried to look for information to do this but I couldn't find any specific and people hardly provide an explanation of the provided solution so this makes difficult to understand how `sed` works.

Basically I have files with the following format:

```
NAME_DIGITS_ddd-11s-21a-ds_DIGITS_DIGITS.xml
```

I want to copy the first DIGITS (e.g `00004574`), which is the string between the first and second underscores.

Any idea of how to do this?

Considering that the first digits could be `0` what can I do to delete them?

I would appreciate any example for these two cases and an explanation would be really welcome too.

I have achieved the opposite: delete the characters between first and second underscores with: `sed s/_[^_]*_/_/` but cannot see how to do what I really need.

Comment: Even after editing it's not entirely clear: do you want to copy all the DIGITS part exactly as written (e.g. `00001234`), or do you also want to remove leading zeros (e.g. leaving just `1234`)?

Comment: Not a duplicate - the OP points out that they know how to match the string but do not know how to match the boundary points.

Comment: Is it a necessary condition that the solution must use `sed`?

Answer (score 3):

```
 awk -F "_" '{print $2}'
```

would do the trick !

Also if you really really want to use sed

```
sed 's/^[^_]*_\([^_]*\)_.*/\1/g'
```

Since sed does not have a non greedy match, we have to search for anything which is not `_` between first and second underscores !

Comment: You can simplify `s/[^_]*_\([^_]*\).*/\1/`

Answer (score 2):

You wrote that you have files with the following format: `NAME_DIGITS_ddd-11s-21a-ds_DIGITS_DIGITS.xml` and you want to copy (extract?) the first DIGITS, between the underscores.

Since your sections are cleanly separated by underscores you can use something like this:

```
echo NAME_DIGITS_ddd-11s-21a-ds_DIGITS_DIGITS.xml | cut -d_ -f2
```

The `cut` command extracts field 2 (`-f2`) using underscore as the specified delimiter (`-d_`)

Comment: If you use the option `-f2,3` it outputs `DIGITS_ddd-11s-21a-ds`. I think it should be just `-f2`.

Comment: @Isaac yes, you're right; I'd misrepresented the question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Other **sed**

```
sed '/\n/!{s/_0*/\n/g;D;};P;d'
```

or

```
sed 's/_0*/\n/;/^[0-9]/!D;P;d'
```

Answer (score 0):

The command you want is:

```
sed -ne 's/^[^0-9_][^_]*_0*\([0-9]*\)_.*/\1/p'
```

Delete the 0* if you want the leading zeros to show up.